# Properties order into Properties File Java

Tags: java, properties

When I execute the following code to create a Properties file, It doesn't respect the order.

```
public Config() {
    this.configFile = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream("resources/config.properties");
        this.configFile.load(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("[ err. ] " + e);
    }
}

public static void initConfig() {
    if(!new File("resources/config.properties").exists()) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("test_key_1", "Value1");
        prop.setProperty("test_key_2", "Value2");
        prop.setProperty("test_key_3", "Value3");
        prop.setProperty("test_key_4", "Value4");
        prop.keySet();
        try {
            prop.store(new FileOutputStream("resources/config.properties"), null);
            System.out.println("[ info ] Configuration file successful created.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("[ err. ] " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm opening the `config.properties`, I have this :

```
test_key_3=Value3
test_key_2=Value2
test_key_1=Value1
test_key_4=Value4
```

and I want to have this :

```
test_key_1=Value1
test_key_2=Value2
test_key_3=Value3
test_key_4=Value4
```

Comment: Properties extends Hashtable, which is an unordered Map.  It will never have consistent ordering.  If you care that much about ordering, you will have to write the data yourself instead of using Properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using another sort of map for storing these properties. The most simple way would be to create it based on already existing `Properties` object.

You didn't mention whether you want to preserve the insertion order or to maintain the so called natural sorting. Depending on the case you may want to use either a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html%20LinkedHashMap) or a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

However you will now have to output the object to a file by yourself, for example:

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new TreeMap<>(yourPropertiesObject);
try(PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(yourOutputFile)) {
  for (Entry<Object, Object> e : map.entrySet()) {
    printer.println(String.format("%s=%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
  }
}
```